# Dataguard parameter changed after DB bounce

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dataguard

I have a production environment of Oracle 11g R2 patchset 4 primary database configured with 2 standby machines.

- Primary database unique_name is **DBIDI**
- 1st standby database unique_name is **DBIFI**
- 2nd standby database unique_name is **DBIGI**.

These unique_names are configured in parameter

```
log_archive_config=DG_CONFIG=(DBIDI,DBIFI,DBIGI)
```

This parameter is configured through Enterprise Manager with My USER with dba grant. Last night we bounced the primary database. After bounce back, the *parameter log_archive_config* is changed and DBIGI is removed from this parameter:

```
log_archive_config=DG_CONFIG=(DBIDI,DBIFI)
```

Can any one tell what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization parameters are not supposed to change while bouncing the database except in one case, that is if the modification was only for currently running instance(`SCOPE=MEMORY`).

The following are the steps to modify initialization parameters using Enterprise Manager.
[image]

> To modify initialization parameters for the currently running instance, and also record the modifications in the server parameter file that will persist when the database is restarted, complete the following steps:
>
> On the Current subpage, in the Value column, enter new values for the initialization parameters.
>
> Select `Apply changes in current running instance(s) mode to SPFile`.
>
> (Optional) In the Comments column, enter text explaining the reasons for the changes.
>
> Click Apply.
>   A confirmation message appears.

[Viewing and Modifying Initialization Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/instance.htm#ADMQS053)